# Meteor: Send data to layout template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Say I have the following html.

```
<template name="Layout">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="Home">
    <div>Home Page</div>
</template>
```

However, data is now passed to Layout. How do I pass data in my `home.js` file to Layout? (In this case, I want to pass a name to `{{name}}`)

Comment: Typo: data is not passed to Layout.

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your app? Are you using `iron:router`?

Comment: @chamrc please edit your question for correcting typos and anything and clarify the question. What data you want pass to what? you written name to `{{name}}`. which does not makes sense

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406970/iron-router-how-do-i-send-data-to-the-layout

Answer (score 0):

you can use paths in data to refer to called data as in {{../name }}

also Template.parentData([numLevels])

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata

Answer (score 0):

The most typical way you share data between your .js files and your templates is via 'helpers'. You can create a simple helper to return the data to your Layout template.

In your JS file, put this anywhere:

```
Template.Layout.helpers({
    name: function() {
        return myVar;
    }
})
```

If you use something like Iron Router, you can have a more 'global' data context for the route (page) you are on. When you are on a 'route' you can simply do this.myVar if its in the route data context.

Hope this helps.