# Iron Router: How do I send data to the layout?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Using Iron Router, I understand how to set data for a template. But how do I send data to a layout that was globally defined?

I set the router layout by:

```
Router.configure({ layoutTemplate: 'NAME' })
```

This will set the layout for all my routes.

However from my individual routes, I'd like to send data to the layout template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout uses the data context defined with `data` in the route option. Here is an excerpt from Iron Router [documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options):

```js
Router.route('/routeName', {
  ...

  // A data function that can be used to automatically set the data context for
  // our layout. This function can also be used by hooks and plugins. For
  // example, the "dataNotFound" plugin calls this function to see if it
  // returns a null value, and if so, renders the not found template.
  data: function () {
    return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },

  ...
}
```

We can also set the data context of the layout with `this.layout` like this:

```js
Router.route('/routeName', function () {
  this.layout('layoutName', {
    data: function() {
      return CollectionName.find();
    }
  });
});
```

In addition, we can refer to an existing `layoutTemplate` option like this:

```js
Router.route('/routeName', function () {
  this.layout(this.lookupOption('layoutTemplate'), {
    data: function() {
      return CollectionName.find();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'NAME',
    data: function() {
        return CollectionName.find();
    }
});
```

As described in the [Global Default Options](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#global-default-options) in the iron:router docs:

> You can set any of the above options on the Router itself...

Where 'above options' is referring to any of the [Route Specific Options](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-specific-options)

You can also `subscribe` to a published Collection:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'NAME',
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.subscribe('CollectionName');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can also add subscriptions specific to a route with waitOn